# Advanced pricing rule not working for specific user group in magento2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-group, price-rules, advanced-pricing

Advanced price rule not working with specific user group. I have created new user group `"Salon"` and created advanced price rule discount for specific product with respect to specific user group `"Salon"` then price rule not working. But when i select `"ALL Groups"` then it is working fine.

[image]

Comment: we can not help you with the information you've provided. Are you 100% sure you are logged in with a customer that is assigned to this exact group?

Comment: yes i am logged-in with specific user group "salon"

Comment: Same issue is coming for me. Advance pricing doest not work for custom Group of customers. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158374)